# individual Div with ID not hiding through Jquery inside form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have multiple divs inside a form tag.

```
  <form id="RegdForm">

@Html.Partial("../Partials/_PatientEdit")
```

The partial view,

```
<div id="zafar"> <h3>Zafar</h3> </div>
```

When I try to hide all the divs its working like below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('Div').hide();
</script>
```

But when I try to hide specific Div it's not hiding at all.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#zafar').hide();
</script>
```

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 with Razor.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: use document.ready, you might be trying to hide element that is not yet added to DOM

Comment: Tried but not working. Is there anythin to do with the form tag as I have another page without form tag and I am able to hide/show divs there.

Comment: @Zafar, It has nothing to do with form tags. Are you sure that you only have one element with `id="zafar"`?

Comment: What does _"yes I have Included"_ mean?

Comment: My query was: Are you sure that you **only have one** element with `id="zafar"`?

Comment: yes the Id is unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78493/discussion-between-zafar-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long googling I found out one solution to this.
As the div was inside the form tag, the way accesing the div can be done as,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#RegdForm #zafar').hide();
```

It helped me to achieve the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#zafar").hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Zafar : It should. Is your internet is on when you are testing it? Because it's downloading JS from the jquery's official site.

and what is "@Html.Partial("../Partials/_PatientEdit")"?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Untitled </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="zafar">
    <h3>Zafar</h3>
</div>
<div class="well well-sm">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bind="click: printPatient">Print</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-bind="click: resetForm">Reset</button>
    </div>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="hideAll">Hide All</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
     $('#zafar').hide();
   });
    $("#hideAll").click(function(){
   $('Div').hide();
 });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your respective function inside this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#zafar').hide();
})
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery library.

Comment: 'code'@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)